# Can you upgrade a room to merge it?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have a room that I upgraded, not realizing that it had space next to it. I tried to merge it with a new room, but it didn't work. If I upgrade the one-off room, will it merge with the existing room?

[image: sample room extension]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it will merge with the other room once you upgrade it to the same tier. It is a net loss in caps, because upgrading a merged room is cheaper than upgrading the individual rooms, but you will have your triple sized room at the end.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wondered!